# How to get text value of span but when its text changed when clicking on same span

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr" style="">
        <div id=":0.targetLanguage" class="goog-te-gadget-simple" style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <img class="goog-te-gadget-icon" src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" style="background-image: url("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/img/te_ctrl3.gif"); background-position: -65px 0px;">
            <span style="vertical-align: middle;">
              <a class="goog-te-menu-value" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <span>Chinese (Simplified)</span>
                <img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif">
                <span style="border-left: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);">​</span>
                <img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif">
                <span style="color: rgb(155, 155, 155);">▼</span>
              </a>
            </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click on google_translate_element(id) OR on span tag inside anchor tag(goog-te-menu-value) after that pop open, that time i select prticular country after that that text inside span tag get changed, i want to take that changed text inside span tag.
 Here i am using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Give your span an id and then use:

```
$("#id").html()
```

Or give your span a class and then use

```
$(".class").html()
```

Comment: Actually I am using Google Api So I am not able to give id or class.
is there any way to resolve that?

Comment: Google must be giving a class itself then. Use that class instead.

Comment: if you are clicking on the span itself then you can user `$(this).html();`

Comment: If i do as per you are saying then it will show same text not the changed text.
When I click on span then pop box open in that i select perticular language then n then only the text inside span get changed. i have to take that changed text inside span tag

Comment: is there any solution for this problem?